# extraxcting meta tags from yahoo videos

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, meta

```
$url="https://screen.yahoo.com/popular/ice-t-voiceover-every-cartoon-182055140.html";
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);
print_r($tags);
```

the result is

```
Array ( [description] => #YahooLive is proud to present this exclusive concert from Los Lonely Boys on Friday, July 31, 2015. Catch the show live or tune in for a full 24 hour rebroadcast. [application-name] => Yahoo Screen [msapplication-tilecolor] => #6e329d [p:domain_verify] => 423db4d61a29a437435ff00f86aa220e )
```

am not able to get all tags including og can anyone help?

Comment: please use the 'view page source' feature of your browser, find the `og` tag (for instance) and then add the html surrounding that to your question. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

> Note:
>
> **Only meta tags with name attributes will be parsed**. Quotes are not required.

To get all the meta tags, you will probably have to parse the HTML yourself. You can use a parser like Simple HTML DOM or similar.